# Measuring thread running time

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

```
public void Foo(IRB inR) {
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    System.Threading.Thread theThread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate() {
            if (inR.Ready) {
                inR.ABC();
                while (!inR.Ready) { Thread.Sleep(100); }
            }
            mP.CP = false;
        });
    theThread.Name = "aaabbbccc";
    theThread.Start();
}
```

So, I want use StopWatch measuring the time that "theThread" running. (Actually, I want to measure time from creating of this thread to end of thread.)
I already put stopwatch.start() where I want. But where should I put my stopwatch.stop()?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not put the stopwatch code *in* the thread itself? For example:

```
public class ThreadTimer
{
    private readonly ThreadStart realWork;

    public ThreadTimer(ThreadStart realWork)
    {
        this.realWork = realWork;
    }

    public void TimeAndExecute()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try
        {
            realWork();
        }
        finally
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            // Log or whatever here
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
ThreadStart work = delegate() {
    if (inR.Ready) {
        inR.ABC();
        while (!inR.Ready) { Thread.Sleep(100); }
    }
    mP.CP = false;
};
ThreadTimer timer = new ThreadTimer(work);
Thread thread = new Thread(timer.TimeAndExecute);
thread.Start();
```

Comment: Could you put all the StopWatch stuff in his delegate as well?

Answer (score 1):

**Can you put it at the end of your delegate?** 
You'd have to join the background thread with the running thread if you create the Stopwatch object as a variable local to your function. Or, you can create it outside the function to let the thread run without joining.

```
public void ConditionPlate(IRB inR)
{

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    System.Threading.Thread theThread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate()
    {
        if (inR.Ready)
        {
            inR.ABC();
            while (!inR.Ready) { Thread.Sleep(100); }
        }
        mP.CP = false;

        // ********************************
        // This will stop the stopwatch.
        // ********************************
        sw.Stop();
    });
    theThread.Name = "aaabbbccc";
    theThread.Start();

    // Wait for the thread to stop (necessary if 'sw' is created here, locally)
    theThread.Join();

    // gets time required for creation of thread to thread completion.
    var elapsed = sw.Elapsed;

}
```

Comment: thank you,but not working for me. theTread stuck in somewhere, cannot to last line of code ever.